# iOS 7 crash related to WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm seeing a crash in Crashlytics only for iOS 7 that I'm unable to reproduce on the simulator. I have code in place which uses UIWebView if iOS 7, and WKWebView if iOS 8. It shows the crash on line 67 as EXC_BREAKPOINT UNKNOWN.

Here's the related code in my viewDidLoad():

```
        if NSClassFromString("WKWebView") != nil {
            let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: webView.frame, configuration: config)
            wkWebView!.navigationDelegate = self // line 67
            wkWebView!.loadRequest(urlRequest!)
            mainView.addSubview(wkWebView!)
            mainView.bringSubviewToFront(toolbar)
            let navBarHeight = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height
            let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
            insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(navBarHeight! + statusBarHeight, 0, toolbar.frame.size.height, 0)
            wkWebView!.scrollView.contentInset = insets
            wkWebView!.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
        } else {
            webView.loadRequest(urlRequest!)
            insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, self.toolbar.frame.size.height, 0)
            webView.scrollView.contentInset = insets
            webView.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
        }
```

Since it's iOS 7, I don't understand how it's even getting inside the if block.

Stack trace (line 85 is closing brace for viewDidLoad):

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  ToC Festival                   0x0024afb4 ToC_Festival.WebViewController.viewDidLoad (ToC_Festival.WebViewController)() -> () (WebViewController.swift:85)
1  ToC Festival                   0x0024a5ec ToC_Festival.WebViewController.viewDidLoad (ToC_Festival.WebViewController)() -> () (WebViewController.swift:67)
2  UIKit                          0x32ef7a53 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 518
3  UIKit                          0x32fa230d -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 32
4  UIKit                          0x32fa2223 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 230
5  UIKit                          0x32fa1801 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 80
6  UIKit                          0x32fa1529 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 572
7  UIKit                          0x32fa1299 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 44
8  UIKit                          0x32fa1231 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 184
9  UIKit                          0x32ef3305 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 380
10 QuartzCore                     0x32b6f31b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 142
11 QuartzCore                     0x32b6ab3f CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 350
12 QuartzCore                     0x32b6a9d1 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
13 QuartzCore                     0x32b6a3e5 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 228
14 QuartzCore                     0x32b6a1f7 CA::Transaction::commit() + 314
15 QuartzCore                     0x32b63f1d CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 56
16 CoreFoundation                 0x3068f039 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
17 CoreFoundation                 0x3068c9c7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 286
18 CoreFoundation                 0x3068cd13 __CFRunLoopRun + 738
19 CoreFoundation                 0x305f7769 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
20 CoreFoundation                 0x305f754b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
21 GraphicsServices               0x355646d3 GSEventRunModal + 138
22 UIKit                          0x32f56891 UIApplicationMain + 1136
23 ToC Festival                   0x001ae0d8 main (AppDelegate.swift:14)
```

Also, here is how I'm implementing the delegate methods for both UIWebView and WKWebView in my WebViewController.swift:

```
extension WebViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}

extension WebViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {
    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        //println("webViewDidStartLoad")
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        //println("webViewDidFinishLoad")
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        //println("An error occurred while loading the webview")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the crash?

Comment: Updated with stack trace.

Comment: Try clean building the project as see if issue still exists.

Comment: Like I said, I'm unable to reproduce this issue. It's happening in Crashlytics reports.

Answer (score 0):

What you're encountering is a bug in the compiler - `NSClassFromString` does not work when optimisations are enabled. You're probably running a Debug build on the iOS Simulator so everything works fine. Try switching to Release configuration, it should crash in the Simulator.

Fortunately there is a workaround - `objc_getClass` works with optimisations so you can replace `if NSClassFromString("WKWebView") != nil` with `if objc_getClass("WKWebView") != nil`.

I've written a blog post about this problem - https://febdev.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/swift-build-problems-in-release/